# Real time OCR in python

Tags: python, image, ocr, image-recognition, python-tesseract

**The problem**

Im trying to capture my desktop with OpenCV and have Tesseract OCR find text and set it as a variable, for example, if I was going to play a game and have the capturing frame over a resource amount, I want it to print that and use it. A perfect example of this is [a video by Micheal Reeves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D75ZuaSR8nQ)
where whenever he loses health in a game it shows it and sends it to his Bluetooth enabled airsoft gun to shoot him. So far I have this:

```
# imports
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import argparse
import cv2
import os

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 5.0, (1366, 768))

while(True):
        x = 760
        y = 968

        ox = 50
        oy = 22

        # screen capture
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x, y, x + ox, y + oy))
        img_np = np.array(img)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        cv2.imshow("Screen", frame)
        out.write(frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 0:
                break

out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

it captures real-time and displays it in a window but I have no clue how to make it recognise the text every frame and output it.

any help?

Comment: Maybe you could show some examples of how it looks?

Comment: probably this is not handwriting and fonts are very repeatable, so there is no need of a real OCR. From the example is

Answer (score 4):

It's fairly simple to grab the screen and pass it to `tesseract` for OCRing.

The PIL (pillow) library can grab the frames easily on MacOS and Windows. However, this feature has only recently been added for Linux, so the code below works around it not existing.  (I'm on Ubuntu 19.10 and my Pillow does not support it).

Essentially the user starts the program with screen-region rectangle co-ordinates.  The main loop continually grabs this area of the screen, feeding it to Tesseract.  If Tesseract finds any non-whitespace text in that image, it is written to *stdout*.

Note that this is *not* a proper Real Time system.  There is no guarantee of timeliness, each frame takes as long as it takes.  Your machine might get 60 FPS or it might get 6.  This will also be greatly influenced by the size of the rectangle your ask it to monitor.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

# Import ImageGrab if possible, might fail on Linux
try:
    from PIL import ImageGrab
    use_grab = True
except Exception as ex:
    # Some older versions of pillow don't support ImageGrab on Linux
    # In which case we will use XLib 
    if ( sys.platform == 'linux' ):
        from Xlib import display, X   
        use_grab = False
    else:
        raise ex


def screenGrab( rect ):
    """ Given a rectangle, return a PIL Image of that part of the screen.
        Handles a Linux installation with and older Pillow by falling-back
        to using XLib """
    global use_grab
    x, y, width, height = rect

    if ( use_grab ):
        image = PIL.ImageGrab.grab( bbox=[ x, y, x+width, y+height ] )
    else:
        # ImageGrab can be missing under Linux
        dsp  = display.Display()
        root = dsp.screen().root
        raw_image = root.get_image( x, y, width, height, X.ZPixmap, 0xffffffff )
        image = Image.frombuffer( "RGB", ( width, height ), raw_image.data, "raw", "BGRX", 0, 1 )
        # DEBUG image.save( '/tmp/screen_grab.png', 'PNG' )
    return image


### Do some rudimentary command line argument handling
### So the user can speicify the area of the screen to watch
if ( __name__ == "__main__" ):
    EXE = sys.argv[0]
    del( sys.argv[0] )

    # EDIT: catch zero-args
    if ( len( sys.argv ) != 4 or sys.argv[0] in ( '--help', '-h', '-?', '/?' ) ):  # some minor help
        sys.stderr.write( EXE + ": monitors section of screen for text\n" )
        sys.stderr.write( EXE + ": Give x, y, width, height as arguments\n" )
        sys.exit( 1 )

    # TODO - add error checking
    x      = int( sys.argv[0] )
    y      = int( sys.argv[1] )
    width  = int( sys.argv[2] )
    height = int( sys.argv[3] )

    # Area of screen to monitor
    screen_rect = [ x, y, width, height ]  
    print( EXE + ": watching " + str( screen_rect ) )

    ### Loop forever, monitoring the user-specified rectangle of the screen
    while ( True ): 
        image = screenGrab( screen_rect )              # Grab the area of the screen
        text  = pytesseract.image_to_string( image )   # OCR the image

        # IF the OCR found anything, write it to stdout.
        text = text.strip()
        if ( len( text ) > 0 ):
            print( text )
```

This answer was cobbled together from various other answers on SO.

If you use this answer for anything regularly, it would be worth adding a rate-limiter to save some CPU.  It could probably sleep for half a second every loop.

Comment: Great job. This is a good snippet of code, and it seems that it answers OP's question. I tested it now, and it works fluently untli "IF(sys.argv[0] in ....)". Returns error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @HavardKleven - Well spotted, it was not checking for the user supplying no screen position arguments.  Please see edit/correction.

Comment: Good example, but bbox is dedfined as `4-tuple defining the left, upper, right, and lower pixel coordinate`. Easily fixed by setting width to x + width and height to y + height. See [PIL.Image.getbbox](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=getbbox#PIL.Image.Image.getbbox)

Answer (score 2):

Tesseract is a single-use command-line application using files for input and output, meaning every OCR call creates a new process and initializes a new Tesseract engine, which includes reading multi-megabyte data files from disk. Its suitability as a real-time OCR engine will depend on the exact use case—more pixels requires more time—and which [parameters](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc) are provided to tune the OCR engine. Some experimentation may ultimately be required to tune the engine to the exact scenario, but also expect the time required to OCR for a frame may exceed the frame time and a reduction in the frequency of OCR execution may be required, i.e. performing OCR at 10-20 FPS rather than 60+ FPS the game may be running at.

In my experience, a reasonably complex document in a 2200x1700px image can take anywhere from 0.5s to 2s using the english fast model with 4 cores (the default) on an aging CPU, however this "complex document" represents the worst-case scenario and makes no assumptions on the structure of the text being recognized. For many scenarios, such as extracting data from a game screen, assumptions can be made to implement a few optimizations and speed up OCR:

- Reduce the size of the input image. When extracting specific information from the screen, crop the grabbed screen image as much as possible to only that information. If you're trying to extract a value like health, crop the image around *just* the health value.
- Use [the "fast" trained models](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_fast) to improve speed at the cost of accuracy. You can use the `-l` option to specify different models and the `--testdata-dir` option to specify the directory containing your model files. You can download multiple models and rename the files to "eng_fast.traineddata", "eng_best.traineddata", etc.
- Use the `--psm` parameter to prevent page segmentation not required for your scenario. `--psm 7` may be the best option for singular pieces of information, but play around with different values and find which works best.
- Restrict the allowed character set if you know which characters will be used, such as if you're only looking for numerics, by changing the whitelist configuration value: `-c tessedit_char_whitelist='1234567890'`.

[pytesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) is the best way to get started with implementing Tesseract, and the library can handle image input directly (although it saves the image to a file before passing to Tesseract) and pass the resulting text back using `image_to_string(...)`.

```py
import pytesseract

# Capture frame...

# If the frame requires cropping:
frame = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w] 

# Perform OCR
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(frame, lang="eng_fast" config="--psm 7")

# Process the result
health = int(text)
```

Comment: Alt ought this is very good explanation, and helps Alitalia, I don’t see how it directly answers the question. OP has a code to capture a live image. Say for example we wanted to capture subtitles at a static, small space on the live feed. How could this be done?

Comment: The code block at the end contains the process to extract text using the image_to_string function with the frame as the input.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I was having the same issue as you so I did some research into it and I'm sure that I found the solution! First, you will need these libraries:

- **cv2**
- **pytesseract**
- **Pillow(PIL)**
- **numpy**

**Installation:**

- To install cv2, simply use this in a command line/command prompt: **pip install opencv-python**
- Installing **pytesseract** is a little bit harder as you also need to pre-install **Tesseract** which is the program that actually does the ocr reading. First, follow this tutorial on how to install [**Tesseract**](https://medium.com/quantrium-tech/installing-and-using-tesseract-4-on-windows-10-4f7930313f82). After that, in a command line/command prompt just use the command: **pip install pytesseract**
  If you don't install this right you will get an error using the ocr
- To install Pillow use the following command in a command-line/command prompt: **python -m pip install --upgrade Pillow** or **python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow**. The one that uses python works for me
- To install NumPy, use the following command in a command-line/command prompt: **pip install numpy**. Thought it's usually already installed in most python libraries.

**Code:**
This code was made by me and as of right now it works how I want it to and similar to the effect that Michal had. It will take the top left of your screen, take a recorded image of it and show a window display of the image it's currently using OCR to read. Then in the console, it is printing out the text that it read on the screen.

```
# OCR Screen Scanner
# By Dornu Inene
# Libraries that you show have all installed
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

# We only need the ImageGrab class from PIL
from PIL import ImageGrab

# Run forever unless you press Esc
while True:
    # This instance will generate an image from
    # the point of (115, 143) and (569, 283) in format of (x, y)
    cap = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(115, 143, 569, 283))

    # For us to use cv2.imshow we need to convert the image into a numpy array
    cap_arr = np.array(cap)

    # This isn't really needed for getting the text from a window but
    # It will show the image that it is reading it from

    # cv2.imshow() shows a window display and it is using the image that we got
    # use array as input to image
    cv2.imshow("", cap_arr)

    # Read the image that was grabbed from ImageGrab.grab using    pytesseract.image_to_string
    # This is the main thing that will collect the text information from that specific area of the window
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cap)

    # This just removes spaces from the beginning and ends of text
    # and makes the the it reads more clean
    text = text.strip()

    # If any text was translated from the image, print it
    if len(text) > 0:
        print(text)

    # This line will break the while loop when you press Esc
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

# This will make sure all windows created from cv2 is destroyed
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I hope this helped you with what you were looking for, it sure did help me!